# Parsing out bit offsets from a hex number in Python

Tags: python, parsing, bit-manipulation, masking, bit

I have a 64-bit hex number inputting into my script
**0x0000040800000000**. I want to take this number and extract bits 39:32.

How is this possible? I have been parsing individual parts of a string and have ended up in a mess.

I was initially converting it into binary and parsing out sections of the string from

```
command_register =  "".join(["{0:04b}".format(int(c,16)) for c in str(command_register)])
```

Comment: I don't understand where `39` and `32` came from? Are you looking for the bits that are `1`? Based on your example those are bits `35` and `42`.

Comment: I'm parsing out bits and writing the associated label and value. So bits 
39:32 - Value A: 0x00 as an example. and then bits 1:0 - Value B: 0x00

Comment: oh! Lots of confusion

Comment: Any ideas from anyone or do I need to elaborate :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to first convert your hex string into an integer and then use normal maths to extract the bits.

Bit numbering is usually done from the least significant bit, i.e. the furthest right when displayed in binary is bit 0. So to extract bits 39:32 (8 consecutive bits), you would simply need a mask of 0xFF00000000. Simply AND your number and shift the result 32 bits to the right.

Using your hex value and extracting bits 39 to 32 would give you a value of 0x08. The following script shows you how:

```
hex_string = "0x0000040800000000"
number = int(hex_string, 16)    # Convert to an integer
mask_39_to_32 = 0xFF00000000    # Suitable mask to extract the bits with

print(f"As hex: 0x{number:X}")
print()
print("Bits 39-32:                         xxxxxxxx")
print(f" As binary: {bin(number)[2:]:0>64s}")
print(f"      Mask: {bin(mask_39_to_32)[2:]:0>64s}")
print(f"AND result: {bin(number & mask_39_to_32)[2:]:0>64s}")
print(f"   Shifted: {bin((number & mask_39_to_32) >> 32)[2:]:0>64s}")
print(f" As an int: {(number & mask_39_to_32) >> 32}")
```

Which displays the following output:

```
As hex: 0x40800000000

Bits 39-32:                         xxxxxxxx
 As binary: 0000000000000000000001000000100000000000000000000000000000000000
      Mask: 0000000000000000000000001111111100000000000000000000000000000000
AND result: 0000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000
   Shifted: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000
 As an int: 8
```

The mask needed for 47 to 40 would be:

```
Bits 47-40:                 xxxxxxxx
 As binary: 0000000000000000111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    As hex: 0xFF0000000000
```

The use of hexadecimal simply makes it less verbose, and clearer once you get used to it. Groups of 8 bits for masks always end up as 'FF'.

The Wikipedia article on [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bitwise_operation&section=3#AND) should help you to understand the process.

Comment: This is exactly what I am getting at. I have a couple dumb questions. What is the mask value : 0xFF00000000 and why is it shifted 32 bits? What is, say, I want the bits 47:40?

Comment: Try printing the mask as binary. Then count which bits are 1, that should give you an idea. Then reverse the procedure to get the mask needed for 47:40.

Comment: So if I need 47:40, the mask would remain the same. I'm assuming the number of ones from 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 shows the bit values I want to keep? So 8 bits following bit 40.

Comment: bits_47_to_40 = (number & 0xFF00000000) >> 40

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's just not clicking to me.

Comment: I have updated things, hopefully this will help make things a bit clearer.